# Difference between Python object reference and variables in cases of mutable and immutable objects

Tags: python, variables, object, cpython

I was reading a book on python:

> Once we have some data types, the next thing we need are variables in which
>   to store them. Python doesn’t have variables as such, but instead has object
>   references. When it comes to immutable objects like ints and strs, there is
>   no discernable difference between a variable and an object reference. As for
>   mutable objects, there is a difference, but it rarely matters in practice."

Now it is not mentioned what is the difference and I am unable to clear myself on this concept.

What is object reference (Is it the memory address for cpython)?
Actually what is a variable is it a name that is bound to the object reference (my understanding of memory reference is, that it is a address in the memory for cpython, clear me on this if I am wrong).

It will be helpful if it can be explained in the light of it's internal implementation in C and how are these things managed and working internally.

Also it would be helpful if some resources may be provided that explain cpython implementation in detail.

Comment: Required reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, a much better explanation.

Answer (score 4):

- You can refer to this link for more the details:[How do I pass a variable by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) or this: https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php
- In C++ there are 3 methods passing an argument to a function
- Pass by value: Normally the value of a variable will be copied and pass to function, so the value of that variable does not change after function changing its value. In python, if you passing an immutable variable (like ints or strs), the value of those variables will not be changing.

Ex: C++

```
void passByValueFunction(int a)
{
    //Changing argument
    a = 20;
}
int main ()
{
    int a = 10;
    std::cout << a;
    passByValueFunction(a);
    //a will not change after passByValueFunction changes its value
    std::cout << a;  
}
```

Ex: Python

```
def passByValue(a):
    a = 20
a = 10
print a
passByValue(a)
# a will not change
print a
```

+ Pass by address and pass by reference: C++ can pass by address (by pointer) or by reference (reference variable). The result is the value of variable will changes after function changing it. In python, if you pass a mutable variable to a function, its value will change.

```
Ex: C++

    void passByRef(int &a)
    {
      a = 20
    }
    int main ()
    {
      a = 10;
      std::cout << a;
      passByRef(a);
      //The value of a will be change
      std::cout << a;
    }
```

Ex: Python

```
def passByRef(list):
  list = [22,33]
list = [11,44]
print list
passByRef(list)
#List will be change
print list
```

Comment: Is your answer how Python 2 worked?  It's not how Python 3 works.  If you try your second example, the list will be the same.  If you did something like list.append(99) inside the function, then list would change, but that's not because of the way it was passed; it's just because lists are mutable.

Answer (score 2):

The author is saying that you may as well ignore the references when it comes to immutable objects, because you will always replace the reference to an `int` or a `str` object with a reference to another such object.

So

```
a = 5
a = a + 10
```

will set `a` to be a reference to a new `int` object. After all, you can't mutate that object directly.

They further distinguish between variables and object references. Python's names (often called variables) do not store the value directly (as you would in C or other languages), they are *always references*. `a = 5` makes `a` a reference to an object of type `int` that has a value of 5, while in `C` it would require `a` to be an `int` variable that holds the value directly.

I would find that explanation confusing too, because what happens with *mutable* objects is that they themselves contain references that you alter. A list is just a sequence of references, each addressed by an index. You can mutate the list by adding more references (extending the list) or by altering the references (assigning to indices).

I strongly recommend you read [Ned Batchelder's *Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), it is a far clearer explanation of how the Python model works.

I'd not worry about how this is implemented in C much. CPython just uses a lot of pointers to struct objects on a memory heap.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But my question is what is the difference between variable and object reference.

Comment: @pranjalkumar: there is none.

Comment: @pranjalkumar: or rather, the author assumes you are familiar with variables in C and wants you to understand that Python names are different.